# Android async task need to be tied to broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have a background service that receives data roughly once per second from an external BT sensor.  That data comes in, and gets sent to the UI using a broadcast intent/receiver.  The live data is displayed in real time.  This all works well right now.

What I need to do now and can't figure out:  Have a button on the UI set up so that it starts a count of data coming in from the broadcast receiver (which is coming in roughly every second - but is not consistent enough to set a clock by), and stops after a given duration like 10 seconds.  Every time new data comes in, it should be added to the total, and then after the duration of 10 seconds, the UI should be updated with the total, along with some message like "the total was 31".

This sounds easy, but using an async task - which seemed like the way to go - has been giving me trouble since I can't really set the task up to run a loop (afaik) since the looping timing needs to depend on the incoming broadcast receipt.

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this if not via async task?  I imagine the solution might be a simple one, but I'm not seeing it.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am working on a similar project and am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

A [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) would help you with the timing issue and if you wanted to go all out you could implement the timer using [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try one of those ideas.